# Jenkins property to clear previous SVN checkout

Tags: jenkins

Looking for the setting that makes jenkins remove previously checked out code, and check out a fresh / latest version of the code before the build.

Answer (score 3):

yes, that's possible. i generated the following step from the "Pipeline Syntax" link in the left nav of each of my pipeline jobs in jenkins. Sample step is "Checkout: General SCM", SCM is "Subversion" and from there you can select a "Check-out strategy" of "Always check out a fresh copy".

```
checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[credentialsId: '196ff1ff-c481-4d2e-922b-e32410f8ee13', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: 'https://mycompany.example.com/svn/MYREPO/crs/trunk']], workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])
```

the key part is:

```
workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']
```

If you're not familiar with declaring how your jobs will build using a Jenkinsfile yet (pipeline functionality), check out https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/. Here's what that "Pipeline Syntax" link looks like in the nav:

[image: Screenshot showing link to Pipeline syntax]

Comment: Thank you for the response Kevin,Can i get screenshot by any chance please. I could not really get "Pipeline Syntax".

Comment: i added a screenshot!

Comment: Hi Kevin, Here is the screenshot of my jenkins http://i.imgur.com/foD3KC4.png ,It seems i do not have this pipeline.

Comment: ok, yeah, only pipeline build plans will have that link. if you're not using pipelines, that calls into question whether you have the pipeline plugins installed and also whether you are using a version of jenkins new enough to support the pipelines functionality. you could try to make a new pipeline job to test this (you'll be happier with pipelines long term), or ignore this answer. :)

Comment: Glad for you prompt response, I am checking further,It seems like pipelines are not being configured. My Jenkins version is 1.626.

Comment: ah yeah, you're hosed with pipeline until you upgrade. https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin says you need at least 1.642.3, but I'd suggest jenkins 2.